# Algorithmic complexity of testing whether a permutation belongs to a subgroup generated by a set of permutations

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations, computational-complexity

Let $S=\{S_1,S_2,S_3,\ldots,S_m\}$ be a set of permutations on $n$ symbols (in other words $S$ is a subset of a symmetric group on $n$ symbols) and $P$ be a permutation on $n$ symbols.
What is the most efficient known algorithm for testing whether $P$ is in the subgroup generated by $S$ ? Computing the subgroup and testing membership is extremely inefficient. Is there a better way ?

PS: I was just playing around with Rubik's cube and that made me interested in abstract algebra and computational complexity a bit more. Unfortunately I have a  very limited background in the subject (I am just a software engineer - not a CS theorist/mathematician)

Comment: There is the [Schreier-Sims algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schreier%E2%80%93Sims_algorithm), but I do not know whether it is the *most efficient known* algorithm.

Comment: It's a pretty good algorithm - polynomial time from what I understood. I wasn't even aware that there was a field of computational group theory.